# Carregamento do Wildfly muito lento, MUITO LENTO

Tags: java, wildfly

Estava estudando `JavaEE7` e utilizando o `Widlfly 11.0.0.CR1`, primeiramente sem nenhuma configuração no próprio servidor, só rodando uma webapp normal, sem muitas coisas, um form, com uma listagem, e o tempo estava OK. 1 minuto no máximo.

Após configurar um `dataSource`, um `security-domain` e um `smtp`, o tempo pra subir o server e deployar a aplicação ficou muito grande.

**1. Subir o server**: 4minuto e alguns segundos

**2. Deployar a web app**: 1 minuto e 25 segundos

Segue partes do arquivo de configuração do servidor com as configurações que mencionei

**standalone.xml**

```
// datasource

<datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/banco" pool-name="bancoDS">
    <connection-url>jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/banco</connection-url>
    <connection-property name="DatabaseName">banco</connection-property>
    <driver>org.postgresql</driver>
    <pool>
        <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
        <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
    </pool>
    <security>
        <user-name>postgres</user-name>
        <password>root</password>
    </security>
</datasource>

//security-domain

<security-domain name="database-login" cache-type="default">
    <authentication>
        <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
            <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/bancoDS"/>
            <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="select senha from SystemUser where email = ?"/>
            <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="select sysRole.roles_name,'Roles'                            from SystemUser_SystemRole sysRole inner join SystemUser                            su on sysRole.SystemUser_id = su.id where su.email = ?"/>
            <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
            <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>

//email

<outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp-gmail">
    <remote-destination host="smtp.gmail.com" port="465"/>
</outbound-socket-binding>
```

Comment: Já tentou analisar no VisualVM quem está comendo tanto tempo?

Comment: cara, eu baixei de novo, fiz tudo do início e agora está rápido de novo, acontece que ainda quero saber qual o problema, pra caso acontecer de novo, eu não precisar fazer todo o trabalho de novo. O que é esse VisualVM?

Comment: Ele te dá os pontos de consumo de CPU e memória da aplicação. Vem com o JDK. Mais detalhes: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VisualVM?wprov=sfti1